# Obtener el valor de una propiedad dentro de un array de objetos JS

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, map

tengo el siguiente array de objetos del cual estoy intentando obtener el valor "gatito2" de la propiedad "hijos" del segundo objeto.

```js
let animales = [
    {tipo: "perro", edad:12, nombre:"rocky"},
    {tipo: "gato", edad:19, nombre:"boby", hijos:["gatito1","gatito2","gatito3"]},
    {tipo: "hamster", edad:2, nombre:"balboa"}
]
```

He intentado con map pero me devuelve todos los gatitos, ademas con 2 valores undefined que nose de donde salieron:

```
[ undefined, [ 'gato1', 'gato2', 'gato3' ], undefined ]
```

Este es el codigo que estoy probando

```js
let animales = [
    {tipo: "perro", edad:12, nombre:"rocky"},
    {tipo: "gato", edad:19, nombre:"boby", hijos:["gatito1","gatito2","gatito3"]},
    {tipo: "hamster", edad:2, nombre:"balboa"}]



const recorrer = animales.map(function(animal){
    return animal.hijos;
})
console.log(recorrer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te esta ocurriendo es que el **.map** intenta buscar la propiedad `hijos` en todos los elementos y como solo lo tienes definido en el de `tipo: "gato"`,  te devuelve `undefined` en el `tipo: "perro"` y el `tipo: "hamster"`.

Para evitar eso utiliza primero **.filter** para que solo te aparezcan los elementos del `tipo: "gato"`:

```
.filter(animal => animal.tipo == "gato")
```

Luego si quieres obtener solo el valor `"gatito2"` puedes poner en el map para que solo muestre el segundo valor del array:

```
 .map(animal => animal.hijos[1])
```

De esta manera quedaría algo asi:

```js
let animales = [
    {tipo: "perro", edad:12, nombre:"rocky"},
    {tipo: "gato", edad:19, nombre:"boby", hijos:["gatito1","gatito2","gatito3"]},
    {tipo: "hamster", edad:2, nombre:"balboa"}]


let recorrer = animales
                  .filter(animal => animal.tipo == "gato")
                  .map(animal => animal.hijos[1]).toString()
                  
console.log(recorrer);
```